# Creating Minimum Bounding Polygon in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, concave-hull

Does anybody know how to create a "minimum bounding polygon" from a set of polygons in QGIS or elsewhere?

For example, in the figure below I can create a Convex Hull per the purple outline, but I'm after a tighter fit that matches the inner reddish shape.  I can do a buffer with a small distance, but there are interior holes that are tedious to delete manually.

[image]

Comment: I think what you are after is a Concave Hull which would make this a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/119663.

Comment: Thanks, great comment and I was not aware of Concave vs Convex Hulls.  Without a "direct" solution in QGIS I may run this in PostGIS via http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ConcaveHull.html or Python if I run across an algorithm.