# Boundary from Points

Tags: qgis, point, point-in-polygon

[image: boundary and points]I have a point cloud and  need to process a very detailed boundary around the outer points. Is there a tool in QGIS? Convex hull is not detailed enough.

Comment: What do you mean by 'detailed enough'? Could you edit your post to share a sketch/diagram of what you are looking for? Also see [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119663/how-to-make-an-outside-buffer-in-qgis/120094#120094).

Comment: I the pic you see the points and a hand drawn boundary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try *Concave hull*, [What are Definition, Algorithms and Practical Solutions for Concave Hull?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/what-are-definition-algorithms-and-practical-solutions-for-concave-hull)

*Concave hull* has a smaller area, and most of implementations allows you to tune how small and precise resulting polygon should be.

Answer (score 12):

In QGIS, many of the **really** good tools are in the processing toolbox; you need 'concave hull':

[image]
[image]

Try it with different threshold values for different levels of detail:

[image]

[image]

Finally, add a 10% buffer around the outside to make it resemble the sketch you provided:

[image]

Comment: And then buffer the result to get the boundary line to look more like the OP's illustration.

Comment: Good point, could make it match perfectly!